# Calculating $\vec{B}(\vec{x})$ outside of a tranversally-magnetized cylinder

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Consider a cylinder with radius $R$, along the $z$-axis.

the cylinder is uniformly magnetized along the $y$-axis with $\vec{M} = M_0 \ \hat{y}$.

What will $\vec{B}(\vec{x})$ be outside of the cylinder?

---

Attempt using the magnetic potential. (taking the approach from Jackson, 2nd ed., p. 197)

Using a Gaussian pill box at the surface, we have that there will be an effective magnetic surface charge density of:

$\sigma_{_M} = \vec{n} \cdot \vec{M} $

where $\vec{n}$ is the outwardly directed normal, then the potential is given by:

$\Phi_{_M}( \vec{x} ) = {-\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{_V} \frac{\nabla' \cdot \vec{M}(\vec{x}')}{|\vec{x} -\vec{x}'|}d^3x' + \frac{1}{4\pi} \oint_{_S} \frac{\vec{n}' \cdot \vec{M}(\vec{x}')}{|\vec{x} -\vec{x}'|}da'}$

The first term will be zero, as the magnetization is uniform throughout the volume.

In the second term, I can see that $\vec{n}' \cdot \vec{M}(\vec{x}') da' = \sigma_{_M} da$ is the magnetic charge at $\vec{x}'$; so the integral for the potential is a sum of charges $\times 1/r$, it makes sense.

Also, going to cylindrical coordinates, it is clear that $\vec{n}' \cdot \vec{M}(\vec{x}') da' =M_0 \cos(\theta)$ (in [A m] (?)). Then I'm guessing one can expand $1/|\vec{x} -\vec{x}'|$ in some clever way and solve it.

However, I'm stuck, I don't know how to evaluate the integral, please help me.